# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application I need to join two tables and I've used this code :

```
Cursor shapes_cur = sq.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name from shapes INNER JOIN shapes ON shape_to_drug.id_shape=shapes.id WHERE shape_to_drug.id_drug =" + drug_id + " WHERE shape_to_drug.id_hp =" + hp_id, null);
```

But application force closed and I get this error in logcat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name from shapes INNER JOIN shapes ON shape_to_drug.id_shape=shapes.id WHERE shape_to_drug.id_drug =360 WHERE shape_to_drug.id_hp =5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two WHERE clauses in your query you should use AND:

```
"SELECT s.name from shapes s INNER JOIN shapes shape_to_drug ON shape_to_drug.id_shape=s.id WHERE shape_to_drug.id_drug =" + drug_id + " AND shape_to_drug.id_hp =" + hp_id
```

Comment: thanks but now im getting ambiguous column name: name (code 1) error

Comment: @Amir_P Please post a new question. Be sure to include the complete error message and the line of code which causes the error.

Comment: The problem is that you should add tables aliases to your query like "SELECT s1.name FROM shapes s1 INNER JOIN shapes s2 ... " and so on. I've updated answer.

Comment: thanks but after using your code there was another problem i solved it myself